# Finding Time interval between two timestamps

Tags: java, timestamp

I am having two Timestamps :

```
Timestamp loggedintime=rs.getTimestamp("LOGIN_TIME");
Timestamp loggedouttime=rs.getTimestamp("LOGOUT_TIME");
```

Now,What i was trying to do is that find the interval between these two timestamps like 15 minutes or 1 hour 10 minutes etc.

But I have no ides how this can be done.So please help me

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Are you saying you don't know how to use `getTime()` and then do the subtraction to give you the milliseconds?  Or are you saying  you don't know how to turn the interval into numbers and words like `"15 minutes"`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
Timestamp loggedintime=rs.getTimestamp("LOGIN_TIME");
Timestamp loggedouttime=rs.getTimestamp("LOGOUT_TIME");
long interval = loggedouttime.getTime() - loggedintime.getTime();
//total hours
long hours = interval / (60 * 60 * 1000);
//time period that should be represented in minutes
long minutes = (interval % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000);
//time period that should be represented in seconds
long seconds = (interval % (60 * 1000)) / 1000;
System.out.println(hours + " hours " + minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec");
```

Note : Please note that interval time is not accurate since milliseconds lesser than a Second (<1000) are not considered

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getTime()` method of [TimeStamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime) class.

Try this

```
long diff = loggedouttime.getTime() - loggedintime.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long login=System.currentTimeMillis();
.
.
.
long logout=System.currentTimeMillis();

long difInSeconds=(logout-login)/1000;

long hours=difInSeconds/3600;
long minutes=difInSeconds%3600;
long seconds=difInSeconds-(hours*3600+minutes*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling on this question after searching: Java now has javax.time, which includes among others ZonedDateTime and Instant, that replaces Timestamp and has a lot more nice methods to deal with time.

Interval isn't included in the standard, but there's a extension: [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) that does.
So you can write something like:

```
Instant loggedintime=rs.getTimestamp("LOGIN_TIME").toInstant();
Instant loggedouttime=rs.getTimestamp("LOGOUT_TIME").toInstant();
Interval loggedInInterval  = Interval.of(loggedintime, loggedouttime);
System.out.println("Total time logged in: " + loggedInInterval);
```